# Adding option to wp_dropdown_categories

Tags: php, wordpress, dropdown, categories

I have the following code that displays a dropdown menu in my Wordpress site with the categories for posts and then displays a post. What I want to do is add an option for 'All Categories'. I don't want to use `'show_option_all'  => 'All Categories',` as this puts the option at the top and I want it at the bottom, and this also gets auto selected when on some page but I won't go into that. Suffice to say I want to manually insert an option at the end of my list.

**here is my code**

```
<form id="category-select" class="category-select" action="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" method="get">
    <?php
      $args = array(
          'show_option_none' => __( 'Select Category' ),
          'show_option_all'  => 'All Categorys',
          'show_count'       => 1,
          'orderby'          => 'name',
          'echo'             => 0,
      );
      $select  = wp_dropdown_categories( $args );
      $replace = "<select$1 onchange='return this.form.submit()'>";
      $select  = preg_replace( '#<select([^>]*)>#', $replace, $select );
      echo $select;
    ?>
    <noscript>
        <input type="submit" value="View" />
    </noscript>
</form>
```

Thanks.

Any help appreciated.

Ian

Answer (score 1):

Best option is to use get_terms() function and create category dropdown as per your requirement.

```html
$terms = get_terms([
    'taxonomy' => $taxonomy,
    'hide_empty' => false,
]);
<select>
foreach($terms as $cat)
{
echo '<option value="'.$cat->term_id.'">$cat->name</option>';
}
<option value="" selected="selected">All Categories</option>
</select>
```